# Selenium - Python, Invalid locator for the login button

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate class booking for my driving school website, its my first time with selenium and I am having trouble finding the element for the log in button. error message :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: invalid locator
```

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  # Or use Chrome or whichever browser you prefer

driver.get('https://booking.bbdc.sg/#/login?redirect=%2Fhome%2Findex')

# Identify the elements you need to interact with. This usually involves finding the right HTML tags and their identifiers (like class, id, or name).
# This is just an example. You will need to replace 'usernameField', 'passwordField', 'submitButton' etc. with the actual identifiers on your website.
username_field = driver.find_element("id",'input-8')
password_field = driver.find_element("id",'input-15')
username_field.send_keys('x')
password_field.send_keys('x')

driver.find_element("class", "v-btn__content").click()
# You'd repeat the process for finding the buttons/fields for booking the class and interacting with them.

time.sleep(10)
```

I have tried right clicking the button and inspecting it. I am not sure which is the appropriate element?

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line:

```
username_field = driver.find_element("id",'input-8')
```

To:

```
username_field = driver.find_element(By.ID, "input-8")
```

You will need below import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Do the same everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The source of error in your code is this line below:

```
driver.find_element("class", "v-btn__content").click()
```

You can solve it with either of the below methods:

1. Using **TAG_NAME** :

   `driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'button').click()`
2. Using **CLASS_NAME** :

   `driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "v-btn__content").click()`
3. Using **CSS_SELECTOR** :

   `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.v-btn__content').click()`

Here's how you may try:

```py
import time
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = Chrome()

driver.get('https://booking.bbdc.sg/#/login?redirect=%2Fhome%2Findex')

driver.find_element(By.ID, 'input-8').send_keys('x')
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'input-15').send_keys('x')

driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.v-btn__content').click()

time.sleep(10)
```